# Overwrite columns based on figures from a previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I the following table in SQL Server:

```
**Table: Volpartition**

Year    Item    Week    Vol Part1   Part2 
2013     1  wk20    0   0       0
2013     1  wk21    0   0       0
2013     1  wk22    300 300     0
2013     1  wk23    30  30      0
2013     1  wk24    400 400     0
2013     1  wk25    500 500     0
2013     1  wk26    60  60      0
2013     1  wk27    60  60      0
2013     2  wk20    0   0       0
2013     2  wk21    0   0       0
2013     2  wk22    300 300     0
2013     2  wk23    30  30      0
2013     2  wk24    400 400     0
2013     2  wk25    500 500     0
2013     2  wk26    60  60      0
2013     2  wk27    60  60      0
```

*Note: part1 and part2 are partition of vol.*

I would like to overwrite my current table and the desired result should look like this:

```
Year    Item    Week    Vol Part1   Part2 
2013     1  wk20    0   0       0
2013     1  wk21    0   0       0
2013     1  wk22    300 300     0
2013     1  wk23    30  30      0
2013     1  wk24    400 400     0
2013     1  wk25    500 0       500
2013     1  wk26    60  0       60
2013     1  wk27    60  0       60
2013     2  wk20    0   0       0
2013     2  wk21    0   0       0
2013     2  wk22    300 300     0
2013     2  wk23    30  30      0
2013     2  wk24    400 400     0
2013     2  wk25    500 0       500
2013     2  wk26    60  0       60
2013     2  wk27    60  0       60
```

The logic is like this: if I have `vol=0 the week before` then it's ok to have `vol=part1`, and then it's ok for 3 week max. After this period `vol=part2`.

I hope you can understand the table columns, I can't insert images.

Many thanks to any suggestion!

Comment: Do you need to update a table or just select?

Comment: Its very confusing what do you want after 3 week vol=part2 lets say wk23 is is after 3 week so i think vol=0 can you please clarify my understanding.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? 2012?

Comment: Do week numbers roll round. Do you have 53 week years, where is year?If parts are partitions can you have part 1 and 2 populated? Finding if vol three weeks ago is 0, is solvable, trying to figure out the "rules" with this much ambiguity is problematic...

Comment: I need to update the table.

Comment: The column with vol should never change, only how the partition is done, so I have to update only columns part1 and part2.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. The example is from a table that contains sales data for 3 years. The idea is that I have to create a script that applies only for an introduction item or a sales restart. So...in the case of a new product I will register sales starting week 22 from 2013, but for the first 3 weeks with sales I want the entire volume to be register in the column part1, after this to be put in column part2. I need this because further in our procedure it will be used in different calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one variation without `LAG` for SQL Server 2008. It uses a couple of common table expressions to get a list of weeks that are ok, then a simple `CASE` to set the correct values in the update.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY week) rn FROM Table1
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT c1.week FROM cte c1, cte c2
  WHERE c2.vol=0 AND c1.rn IN (c2.rn+1, c2.rn+2, c2.rn+3)
)
UPDATE Table1
SET Part1 = CASE WHEN Week IN (SELECT * FROM cte2) THEN Vol ELSE 0 END,
    Part2 = CASE WHEN Week IN (SELECT * FROM cte2) THEN 0 ELSE Vol END;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4d48/1).

Note that this query currently does not take year into account, since it's not in the sample data you've given.

EDIT: Here is a version that takes item and year into account;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY year, week) rn
  FROM volpartition
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT c1.item, c1.year, c1.week
  FROM cte c1 JOIN cte c2 ON c1.item=c2.item 
   AND c1.rn IN (c2.rn+1, c2.rn+2, c2.rn+3)
  WHERE c2.vol=0
)
UPDATE v
SET Part1 = CASE WHEN c.item IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE Vol END,
    Part2 = CASE WHEN c.item IS NULL THEN Vol ELSE 0 END
FROM volpartition v
LEFT JOIN cte2 c ON v.item = c.item AND v.year = c.year AND v.week = c.week;
```

[Another SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4581a/2).

Comment: Thanks for this! Indeed it works for one item as in my sample data. Can you help me with the changes in the case when I need to take into account the year and different items?

Comment: @user3129376 Sure... could you add how you're representing years in the sample data of the question?

Comment: I've added a new column for Year and rows for a different item. I've left the same figures for item2 as for item1, but of course they can be different. Also, although I didn't add values for a different year it can be added in the same manner as for item.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear so let me guess. In MSSQL you can use [LAG()](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) function with an offset from the current row.
If you need to select then try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select t.*,
       LAG(Vol,3) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L3,
       LAG(Vol,2) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L2,
       LAG(Vol,1) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L1
FROM t
)
SELECT 
[Item],[Week],[Vol],
CASE WHEN L1=0 OR L2 = 0 OR L3 =0 
THEN [Part1]
ELSE 0
END as PART1,
CASE WHEN L1=0 OR L2 = 0 OR L3 =0 
THEN 0
ELSE Vol
END as PART2

FROM CTE
ORDER BY Week
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0fdc6/6)</kbd>

If you need update a table then:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select t.*,
       LAG(Vol,3) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L3,
       LAG(Vol,2) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L2,
       LAG(Vol,1) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as L1
FROM t
)
UPDATE CTE 
SET 
PART1 = 
CASE WHEN L1=0 OR L2 = 0 OR L3 =0 
THEN [Part1]
ELSE 0
END,
PART2=
CASE WHEN L1=0 OR L2 = 0 OR L3 =0 
THEN 0
ELSE Vol
END

WHERE Vol<>0;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fc1bd/1)</kbd>

**UPD:** 
   Instead of `ORDER BY WEEK` I think you should extract Week number and cast it to `Int` to make a right order for `wk1` and `wk100` for example. Something like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(Week,3,1000) as INT)
```

**UPD2:**
  If your SQLServer version doesn't support `LAG()` function then instead of calculate `L1,L2,L3` you can calculate following field and then replace  `CASE WHEN LI=0 OR L2=0 OR L3 = 0` with `CASE WHEN flag = 0`

```
ISNULL((SELECT MIN(Vol) FROM t as t1 
 where 
   CAST(SUBSTRING(t.Week,3,1000) as INT)-
   CAST(SUBSTRING(t1.Week,3,1000) as INT) 
   between 1 and 3
),0) as flag
```

Comment: Note that `LAG` assumes SQL Server 2012, which may or may not be the case.

Comment: I'm not using SQL Server 2012. Is 2008.

Comment: @user3129376 See `UPD2` to my answer in this case.